# Debian VNC (Remote Desktop) only allowing first connection, then turns off

Tags: debian, desktop, vnc, remote

Basically if I reboot the machine, I can `vnc` into it (using ultra vnc) but I can only do it once. It seems that the `vnc` daemon stops working after the first remote desktop session is closed. I have to reboot the machine to VNC into it…

I've ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, the system is up to date… I can't figure out why it will only work once.

Comment: how are you calling the vnc server, what cli options on the client and server?

Comment: I usually enable it from the GUI
System -> Preferences -> Remote Desktop

I have like 20 other machines set up the same way and they have no problems

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding `-alwaysshared` to allow shared connections. There's also another argument that turns off the 'close on disconnect' behavior you are seeing.

Please check the manual page for the `vnc` server you are running. I'd give you the argument myself, but the server(s) I have available to check on do not document this argument as they do not default to this behavior.

Comment: I'm using the default VNC that comes with debian
it's called Vino
I usually run these commands to set it up
`gconftool-2 -s -t bool /desktop/gnome/remote_access/enabled true`

`gconftool-2 --type bool --set /desktop/gnome/remote_access/prompt_enabled 0`

`gconftool-2 --type list --list-type string --set /desktop/gnome/remote_access/authentication_methods '[vnc]'`

`gconftool-2 --type string --set /desktop/gnome/remote_access/vnc_password $(echo -n 'mypassword'|base64)`

Comment: Ick. You might consider running something like xtightvnc instead - a bit of a pain, but probably more flexible in the end. As well, it doesn't use gconf which is a selling point in and of itself!

Comment: Ehh, I'm only having a problem with this one machine. I have 20 more or so running the exact same configuration and they are all working fine... I'll try getting an image from another one and flashing it onto this one.

Thanks

Comment: Seen some exit vnc-on-disconnect too, like for x11vnc, that has a persistence option: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/x11vnc_opts.html#opt-forever. Might be that you have something in a rather hidden place like under */etc/default/*?

Answer (score 0):

Any vnc server supports  share desktop feature. Please check the man of your vnc server.